# how to send formBody parameters using rn-fetch-blob to fetch Data?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

i want to make Post Request Using formBody parameters using rn-fetch-blob. please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of `formdata` that you want.

**Multipart/form-data example**

```js
  RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'http://www.example.com/upload-form', {
    Authorization : "Bearer access-token",
    otherHeader : "foo",
    'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
  }, [
    // element with property `filename` will be transformed into `file` in form data
    { name : 'avatar', filename : 'avatar.png', data: binaryDataInBase64},
    // custom content type
    { name : 'avatar-png', filename : 'avatar-png.png', type:'image/png', data: binaryDataInBase64},
    // part file from storage
    { name : 'avatar-foo', filename : 'avatar-foo.png', type:'image/foo', data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(path_to_a_file)},
    // elements without property `filename` will be sent as plain text
    { name : 'name', data : 'user'},
    { name : 'info', data : JSON.stringify({
      mail : 'example@example.com',
      tel : '12345678'
    })},
  ]).then((resp) => {
    // ...
  }).catch((err) => {
    // ...
  })
```

Comment: why any https url is not working in react native. it is working  fine in ios but after ssl certification any webservices is not working in  android. even images not workin with https url. please i need solution

Comment: @PrajapatiJigar It depends on your React-native version. If the React-native version is installed at 0.46 or later, this problem could be solved.

Comment: 0.57.1 version i am using

Comment: this is not the solution

Comment: What is the version of your Android device?

Comment: Https is supported starting with Android 9.

Comment: please i am working for 10 days but still did not get the solution

Comment: Is the simulator Android version 9 or higher?

Comment: i have chcked both in android 9 and marshmallow but it is not working on any one

Comment: Please refer https://gist.github.com/seriiix/093289bb28747e26301432a5fba6b060 , https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23151

Comment: @PrajapatiJigar First of all, I can't see your Android files. And your questions differ in scope from 
the questions in the postings. If my answer helped the question,I think it would be advisable to you choose an my answer and post a new question after the question has been closed.